# C# "File couldn't copy" during build

Tags: c#

error MSB3030:

> Could not copy the file "obj\Release\Hotel Management System.dll" because it was not found.

But the Hotel Management System.dll file is inside the bin folder

And i got a runtime error

> Parser Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message:

> Could not load type 'Hotel_Management_System.MvcApplication'.

Source Error:

> Line 1:  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="Hotel_Management_System.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>

Source File: /global.asax    Line: 1

> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.2116.0

Comment: obj and bin are not the same thing. Why are you copying from obj?

Comment: use bin instead of obj

Answer (score 1):

use bin instead of obj, the output build would place in bin folder